# 'requirement tdd' issue when installing 'micom' PyPI on the PyCharm enviroment

Tags: python, pycharm, tbb

I tried to install a `PyPI` named `micom` in the PyCharm environment. 
But, when I wrote code on the python terminal as

```
pip install micom
```

The following error is showing:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tbb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tbb
```

My pip version is the latest (`v20.1.1`) 
I thought there is some problem in `umap-learn` or `tdd`, so I tried to install both through `project interpreter +` at the `PyCharm`, but it didn't work with same error ;

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tbb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tbb
```

I have done Googling, but it is not easy to find troubleshooting about this `tdd` issue.

Can you give me any advice on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One of the dependencies of `micom` is `umap-learn>=0.4.1`. The latter relies on `tbb`. Somehow, when trying to install `umap-learn`, the installation fails on installing `tbb`. That seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap/issues/435). I suggest to follow the advice of an answer posted there:

> This has been an intermittent problem that I have had difficulty
>   tracking down. In the worst case you can grab the latest version off
>   github and, prior to installing, just remove tbb from the requirements
>   (including in setup.py). That should resolve the problem and it will
>   likely work without tbb for the most part.

That would entail cloning the latest version of `umap-learn` from [GitHub](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) and removing the `tbb` requirement from `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`. You can then try to install `umap-learn` by running `pip install .` in the root of the cloned GitHub repository.

Comment: I run the command, 'pip3 install micom' , but it showed same error as 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tbb (from umap-learn>=0.4.1->micom) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tbb (from umap-learn>=0.4.1->micom)'     and i  checked my python version is v3.7.3 at PyCharm by commanding 'python --version'

Comment: I found that my type of python was 32bit (my laptop 63bit ) I have solved this tdd issue by re-installing the proper one(64 bit python v3.7.7.) But, I thank for your advice and I will refer it when counting similar problem.